# why my Authoritative DNS Server on Ubuntu 18.04 not working after server ip changed?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, ip, linux-networking

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS server that I ran both authoritative DNS and web server on it.

I use BIND 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.9-Ubuntu for DNS system.

Everything was just fine until for some reason I had to change the server IP address. After that my DNS fails to resolve the IP address.

I've already changed db.domain file and updated the old IP to the new one, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: *"my DNS fails to resolve the IP address"* is somewhat unspecific. Please show us the output of running a command like `dig @192.0.2.1 example.com soa +norec` from a system other than the authoritative DNS server, replacing your authoritative DNS server's IP address and your domain name as appropriate. If that gives you a correct DNS response, you can also try replacing `+norec` with `+trace`.

Comment: the problem solved by Tomek answer, but in a hard way, i didn`t have the access to glue record ip address, i had to ask my domain holder company to set the name server ip in glue record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DNS server name belongs to the zone it is serving then you also need to update "glue" records at your parent zone to point to new ip address of your authoritative DNS server.